# How do i recover my storyboards after git reset --hard HEAD^?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git

About a week ago, I was pushing my .gitignore file to my repository and was running into small issues with that, and finally figured it out, but noticed that all my storyboards were in the repository too. In a stroke of genius, I looked into getting them out of there and found out about the above git reset command and just put that into my terminal and patted myself on the back and life went on. I just realized today after installing some cocoapods that all my storyboards I spent weeks working on are gone and put two and two together. I've spent the last hour reading through the similar questions, but haven't found anything after reading for a while and am wondering if any other xcode users have run into the same issue and can help.

I should also add that I had only added the storyboards to the stage and hadn't committed them yet at the time of the reset, so today I was using the git reflog command in hopes that they were in the lost and found. I had read that the garbage collection doesn't happen for a month so I don't think (I hope) they're just gone

I downloaded the AWS SDK today and that's all the git reflog command seems to be showing at the moment. Do I need to roll back the git rest HEAD{} command further?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do the commits with the storyboards show up when you run git reflog?

Comment: I've been doing the git show command and haven't been able to find them yet now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You note in a comment that you did a `git stash`

This is a crucial bit of information, which changes everything.  Fortunately, it also makes recovering much easier.  In particular it means that your missing files are not "dangling blobs" and *do* have their original names saved.  (Note, by the way, that `git stash` means `git stash save`; I'll use the longer form below to distinguish it from other `git stash` commands.)

The simplest way to recover is to use `git stash branch`.  Pick a *new* branch name, one that you do not yet have.  For illustration I will use `saveme`, which is a terrible name and you should choose a better one.

```
git stash branch saveme
```

This will take your existing `git stash`, create a *new* branch using the commit that was current when you ran `git stash save`.  It will then restore your index (staging area) to the way it was at the time you ran `git stash save`, *and* restore your work-tree to the way it was at the time you ran `git stash save`.  You can now commit the index:

```
git commit -m 'save index as a commit'
```

and then commit the rest of the work-tree if there is anything else to commit:

```
git add --all
git commit -m 'save everything else as a commit too'
```

I will add, at the end of this answer (in another edit), a pictorial diagram of what happens with this entire sequence, starting from the first `git add`s and going through the `git stash save` and `git reset --hard HEAD^` and on to the final `git stash branch`.

---

There is one caveat: your index and work-tree must be clean to use `git stash branch`.  If you have uncommitted work, you probably should commit it now, or throw it all out with `git reset --hard`.  Of course, either one has consequences:

- If you run another `git stash save`, the earlier saved stash gets "pushed up" from `stash@{0}` to `stash@{1}`.  You will then have to use:

  ```
  git stash branch saveme stash@{1}
  ```

  to convert that stash to a branch.
- If you choose to use `git reset --hard`, you lose any uncommitted work you have, so be sure that this is OK.

#### Pictorial diagram

Let's take a look at a hypothetical terminal session, and see what happens with your commits and branches as you work.

```
$ cd my-git-project
```

At this point, you are in a Git work-tree.  The work-tree is where your files are in their normal form, that the rest of the computer (and you) can work with, instead of their Git-only form, where Git saves *every* version of *every* file you or anyone else has *ever* committed.  You are on some branch—let's say `master`, just for concreteness.  This branch has some set of commits, ending in what Git calls the *tip* commit of that branch.  The branch *name* remembers the hash ID of this tip commit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Each uppercase letter represents a normal, ordinary commit.  (In other words, these stand in for the incomprehensible hash IDs that are the actual names of each commit.)  Commit `H` is the latest one.  If your index / staging area and work-tree are "clean", the files in them match those in commit `H`.

Now you make some changes, and stage some or all of them:

```
$ ... edit some files ...
$ git add file1 file2 ...
```

The staging area, aka index, is now not "clean": it no longer matches commit `H`.  Instead, it has copies of the edited and added files.

Your work-tree may or may not match your index.  If it *does* match your index, and if you were to run `git commit`, Git would make a new commit out of your index (that's what the index / staging-area is for, mainly: to build the next commit), and then your index would match your commit and be clean.  If your work-tree matches your index, that too would then be clean.  This would look like:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

where `I` is the new commit, made from your index.

Instead, though, you ran `git stash save`.  What this does is make *two* commits, neither of which is on the branch:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
           |\
           i-w   <-- stash
```

The first (lowercase `i`) commit is the *same* commit that `git commit` would have made.  It's just not on branch `master`; it's part of this two-commit "stash bag".  The second commit, `w`, is peculiar: it looks to the rest of Git like a merge commit, but in fact it's just a commit of your work-tree state, even if that's the *same* as the index state in `i`.

After making these two stash-bag commits, `git stash` resets (cleans) your index and work-tree, a la `git reset --hard HEAD`.  So now your index and work-tree match commit `H` again.

Next, you say you ran `git reset --hard HEAD^`.  This does *three* things: it resets the index and work-tree state to the state of the selected commit, which is the one just before `H`; and it makes the name `master` *point to* the selected commit as well.  So now your repository looks like this:

```
...--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H   [remembered in reflogs, *and* preserved via the stash]
          |\
          i-w   <-- stash
```

Note that the stash-bag is still there, and still find-able by the name `stash`.  The two stash-bag commits remember commit `H` by its hash ID.  Meanwhile, the name `master` now remembers the hash ID for commit `G` instead—and your index and work-tree are "clean", i.e., match that for `G`.

If you now run `git stash branch saveme`, this is what Git does in terms of *commits*:

```
...--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H   <-- saveme
          |\
          i-w   [abandoned]
```

The index is re-loaded from the `i` commit, and the work-tree is re-loaded from the `w` commit.  If you now run `git commit` you get:

```
...--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H--I   <-- saveme
```

since Git saves the index as a new commit `I`.  The work-tree remains unchanged; if it's clean with respect to `I`, it's now all clean, and if not, you can `git add` any remaining changes and commit them:

```
...--F--G   <-- master
         \
          H--I--J   <-- saveme
```

and now everything is saved permanently (or until you delete the `saveme` branch) in plain, ordinary commits that you can work with in the usual ways.  Note that commit `H`, which you threw into the recycling bin with `git reset --hard HEAD^`, has *come back* on the new branch.

---

#### Original answer

> I should also add that I had only added the storyboards to the stage and hadn't committed them yet at the time of the reset ...

This makes things harder, because:

> ... so today I was using the `git reflog` command

`git reflog` looks only at abandoned *commits*.

> ... in hopes that they were in the lost and found.

They may still be!  The "lost and found" is separate from the reflogs.

> I had read that the garbage collection doesn't happen for a month so I don't think (I hope) they're just gone

The 30-day grace period is specifically for *commit* objects that are remembered in reflogs, which these are not.  However, *all* objects get a 14-day grace period.  The clock starts at the time you `git add` the file to the staging area.  (Even once the clock runs out, it takes a later `git gc --auto` to make the files go away, but it's hard to know when that will happen.)

Actually *finding* your files is a bit trickier.  Run:

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

which, as [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fsck.html) says:

> `--lost-found`
>
>   Write dangling objects into .git/lost-found/commit/ or
>     .git/lost-found/other/, depending on type. If the object is a blob,
>     the contents are written into the file, rather than its object
>     name.

Since you did `git add` these files, and they presumably never were in any commit, they will be "dangling" objects of type "blob".  The `git fsck` command will print a bunch of incomprehensible hash names.  You can then change into the `.git/lost-found/other/` directory and examine all the files there, which all have these hash names.  In amongst all these files, the contents you `git add`ed will appear.

For each such file, figure out whether it should be saved away under which sensible file name, and move the file out of the `lost-found/other` area to one of that name, and you have that file back.

Comment: A quick googling showed me how to do it and I see some files that are my storyboards. Is there a way to just add every file in the other directory? Or do I have to go through each one and find my storyboards?

Comment: The original file names are gone, and the files are mixed with other dangling blobs (however many of those there may be, possibly none, possibly very many) so you *will* need to go through all of them, and sort out which ones to keep by which names.

Comment: I realized earlier that I stashed the storyboards files before doing the reset (thankfully) I am trying to do a git stash apply, but have run into a merge conflict. How do i resolve this? will the Stash apply restore my files in xcode again?

Comment: Aha, this changes everything, because `git stash` makes commits!  Specifically, `git stash save` makes at least *two* commits, one of your index / staging-area (hence committing all the `git add`-ed files), and one of your work-tree (hence committing all the files you had not yet `git add`ed).

Comment: So then what is the procedure next that will allow me to recover my storyboards back into xcode? I saw they were there when i ran the git show -p command.

Comment: I'm editing the answer, since `git fsck --lost-found` is no longer a useful method (the fact that you have the stash keeps the blobs from being "dangling"!).

Comment: I dont know if this helps at all, but I copied this from the terminal after scrolling up to see what I did last week.  git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 341a9a3 commiting gitignore file
HEAD is now at 341a9a3 commiting gitignore file

Comment: I can't tell you how much I appreciate the time you've taken to thoroughly explain what's going on and I fell I have a better grasp of how this works a little more. I do have another question. Before making this question on stackoverflow I did follow another answer I had seen online and ran the git reset HEAD{} command all the way back as far as i would let me. How does this effect how I proceed with the git stash branching going forward?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `HEAD{}`; there's a `HEAD@{...}` syntax (with `@`-sign character and, normally, contents within the braces; see https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html). But `git reset` resets up to three things: the target commit for the current branch name; the index, and the work-tree. It *always* moves the current branch name to the commit you specify. It then optionally resets the index to that commit (`--mixed`, which is the default) and also optionally resets the work-tree (if you use `--hard`).

Comment: So for example when I ran git reflog before doing any resetting and saw there were 6 HEADs,  when I ran git --hard reset HEAD{6} that moved the current branch, which would be master in my case, to the very first commit i made at the time and also reset the work tree to that first branch too. is that correct? so if the work tree looked like --F--G--H--I--J-=K and i  reset back to --F and used --hard my current master branch and work tree is back at --F then? If you saw the comment i made earlier before the last, can I reset again to that specific work tree where I ran the git stash initially?

Comment: Well, exact spelling (like exact command sequences) is pretty critical here, but yes, `HEAD@{6}` (note both the @ and the number between the braces) means "the sixth previous value of HEAD". But: "can I reset again to that specific work tree": remember that the *work tree* is, to Git, simply a scratch area. It's not a commit, so it's not remembered. You can recover the `w` *commit* made by `git stash`, and that's what `git stash branch` will do.

Comment: I see, I see. I went to run the git stash branch command and it said that i needed to merge with my project/pbxproj. I haven't done any merging yet, but i did run  the git status command and it shows all my story board files waiting to be committed. How is this possible if the git status branch needs the merge to happen before it can run? Also how do I run the merge command so that I don't mess anything else up? I'm sorry for all the questions i just really don't want to break anything again

Comment: It sounds like your `git stash apply` was able to get them all back, despite whatever else may have gone wrong.  (See "There is one caveat: your index and work-tree must be clean to use git stash branch. If you have uncommitted work ..." above.)  You're understandably nervous, but rest assured that once files are *committed* on a branch, it's really hard to get Git to forget them.  And until you get your stash applied and dropped, or converted to a branch, the stash itself sticks around unless you explicitly `git stash drop` it (so don't do that!).

Comment: The other thing to know is that unless you have data you really don't want anyone else to see (passwords, secret pet name for girlfriend, whatever :-) ), you should never be afraid to make a *new* commit, perhaps on a new branch (`git checkout -b newbranch`), so that everything tracked gets saved forever. It's really hard to lose it once it's committed.

Comment: when I went to commit, I received this message error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict. does this mean I have to move up the work tree like your example shows? Will my storyboards be gone if I do this?

Comment: Ah, well, that's the effect of your `git stash apply`, then: it got some files back fine, but got "merge conflicts" on others. `git status` tells you *which* files have merge issues. I don't know if you started with a clean work-tree when you ran `git stash apply`, so I don't know if it's safe to do `git reset --hard` *now*.

Comment: Looking back, I did the git stash the first time, it was on the master branch if that helps. I knew nothing about work-trees and the like a week ago.

Comment: Well, I don't know *exactly* what you did, so any advice I can give is limited. But *if* you had a clean state when you ran `git stash apply`, you can `git reset --hard` to get back to that state, and then use `git stash branch` to convert the two special stash commits, as described above. Alternatively, you can try finishing the ongoing merge (read about Git merge and resolving merge conflicts), or just salvage what you have in your current work-tree. (I actually don't recommend `git stash` much: when it works it's great, but when it fails, you need to know everything about merging anyway.)

Comment: Well, at the time before I made any mistakes, I was only trying to push my .gitignore file to my repository. I ran git status and saw all my story boards were staged but i knew I didn't want to push them to the repository and I thought committing was the same as pushing at the time. So I only committed my .gitignore files and left the other storyboards in staging.I then added my repository and attempted to push the .gitignore file to there and kept running into conflicts because the branch . was on was behind. after many git pull requests, I finally did a git checkout.

Comment: After doing git checkout twice, I ran the git merge multiple times and ran into errors and then tried to run git pull multiple times again. After that I ran git add so that all the files in red would be green and everything was staged. I ran git pull one more time and got another error so I ran git stash. After that I ran git pul and git push many times thinking my .gitignore file still wasnt there. finally i ran git push origin 341a9a3:master -f which finally worked and then I ran git reset --hard HEAD^ because I saw my storyboards in the repository and didnt want them there.

Comment: This was all a week ago. Yesterday after realizing i goofed up I made the changes that I listed in the earlier comments. I just checked and saw that my old story board files are actually back in xcode though i have no clue how, but now I can't open my project that I had before. Is this from doing the reset from yesterday? My confusion has only grown, despite all the help you've patiently given me.

Comment: Hmm ... I'd say, depending on what sort of time you have available, you might want to step back entirely from Xcode and just spend some time poking around with nothing but Git, on a separate project where you experiment with things, to get used to how Git works. I have not used Xcode for anything serious, I just played with it a little bit once, but as I recall it adds its own layering of stuff atop everything (has its own notion of "workspace", like many GUIs) which will not help with confusion!

Comment: Very sound advice that I, sadly, don't have the luxury of time to pursue at the moment. However I do have good news. I stopped freaking out about how scary the terminal and git was to me and did a git reset--hard HEAD @{7} which took me back to the last head where I knew for sure I had made the stash. sure enough that's where all my storyboards were. I went ahead and applied the stash and then quickly committed all those files. After opening xcode again I found that everything was back right as I left it as though I hadn't made any mistakes.

Comment: I could honestly kiss you the biggest hug ever, torek. You will never know how honestly grateful I am that you've taken so much time to help me and be so patient and give me such thorough answers. I'm gonna go ahead and mark this as the right answer. Thank you very much!